# How to inject code into Magento admin template

Tags: magento

I have to add a snippet of code to each of the following adminhtml templates:

```
shipment/create/form.phtml
shipment/view/form.phtml
creditmemo/create/form.phtml
creditmemo/view/form.phtml
invoice/create/form.phtml
invoice/view/form.phtml
```

So there are 6 templates in total and all will require a associated layout code to replace the template from default magento to my custom template.

All for the sake of adding a single line of code to echo something out.

Now, I cannot see it, but is there a way for me to add my code somehow to these templates but not have to replace the default magento templates with my customized version?

Comment: It really depends on at what place you want you code to be added. In some cases adding a new block through XML layout may work.

Comment: An example position would be line 47/48 in invoice/create/form.phtml and it will be roughly the same for each of the examples i provided in my question

Comment: Sorry, but I think you will not be able to do it w/o creating your versions of templates.

Comment: Ok, this is what i am finding.  I was hoping there would be some clever way to do this.  Feels wrong to override all of those templates for something so small

Comment: Yes, I was at the same place several times. Hope this will change in Magento2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to change templates *necessarily*. Adminhtml rendering is the same as frontend rendering, including fallback. Specify a custom theme for the admin store in your module's config:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <template>your_theme</template>
                    <!-- or <default>your_theme</default> -->
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

You'll need a different approach if this will be a distributed module, or you'll need to advise customers using your extension of the custom template. This approach doesn't work prior to CE1.6.1.0 [due to the `Find_Feed` module](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.6.0.0/app/code/community/Find/Feed/etc/config.xml#L125).

In that case, you can use layout update XML to change the templates which are used as you've described. This isn't ideal if a user is already using custom templates for these blocks - unlikely but possible. If worse comes to worse, you can always observe the [`core_block_abstract_to_html_after`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L886) event as a last resort.